# Inferred Type and Dynamic typing

Tags: type-inference, dynamic-typing

In programming language what is the difference between Inferred Type and Dynamic typing? I know about Dynamic typing but don't get how dynamic typing is differ from Inferred Type and how? Could someone please provide explanation with some example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Inferred type = set ONCE and at compile time. Actually the inferred part is only a time saver in that you don't have to type the Typename IF the compiler can figure it out.

  Type Inference is often used in conjunction **static typing** (as is the case with swift) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference)
- Dynamic type = no fixed Type -> type can change at runtime

---

static & inferred example:

```
var i = true; //compiler can infer that i most be of type Bool
i = "asdasdad" //invalid because compiler already inferred i is an Bool!
```

it is equal to

```
var i: bool = true; //You say i is of type Bool
i = "asdasdad" //invalid because compiler already knows i is a Bool!
```

==> type inference saves you spell out the type if the compiler can see it

BUT if it were dynamic that would work (e.g. objC) as the type is only based on the content at RUNtime

```
id i = @YES; //NSNumber
i = @"lalala"; //NSString
i = @[@1] //NSArray
```

Comment: Are you saying Inferred type = static typing?

Comment: yes. it just saves you from typing the type if the compiler can figure it out anyways

Comment: I didn't get it..But In Static typing we deliberately provide the data type. Could you provide some example pls for Inferred type?

Comment: does the edit help you? else study the link to wikipedia I provided

Answer (score 1):

you can change data type on the fly for dynamic typing, but inferred typing does not require explicit data type declaration before use.

Answer (score 0):

Static and dynamic typing tell you when the type of the variables is checked.
Static typing checks the type during compilation. Dynamic typing checks the type during runtime( on the fly)

Inferred and Manifest concerns whether you have to specify the type of the variable or not. Inferred means that the language will detect it for you. Manifest means that the type must be specified.