# What is 'type' being associated with value or variable?

Tags: dynamic, static, programming-languages, theory

I am trying to understand what are the different 'typing disciplines' in programming. I found there are Dynamic and Static typing disciplines.

In [Static typing](http://progopedia.com/typing/static/), Types are associated with variables (as opposed to values). And in [Dynamic typing](http://progopedia.com/typing/dynamic/), Types are associated with values (as opposed to variables).

I have linked where I read this...

So, what does type being associated with variable or value mean?

Answer (score 2):

Static typing means that the programmer or its compiler declare the data type of the variable. The variable will then only accept that kind of data, i.e. the type is associated with the variable. For example, in Java:

```
int price_of_donut;
```

`price_of_donut` has been assigned an `int` data type. The variable will only accept `int`s in your program. It could be `0`, `2`, `5000000`, but not  `"free"`, as the word "free" is a `string`.

On the other hand, dynamic typing means that the data type of the variable is dependent on its input, i.e. the type is associated with the value. For example, this program in Python:

```
price_of_donut=2.99
price_of_donut='free'
```

Notice how there is no declaration of data type before the variable (No declaration is needed).

`price_of_donut` in the first line is a `float`, but in the second line `price_of_donut` turns into a `string`. The program will run with no problems.

---

So you might ask: Which one's better?

- Dynamic typing makes for an easier coding experience since you type less and potentially use less variables, but the programmer has to keep in mind the data types of variables during coding, whether it changes mid way or not. If a crash occurs, the program might not tell you the right place to look.

Consider this situation: a data type changes in line 81 of your program, but the crash happened on line 246 of your program, and the program tells you something went wrong on line 246. You look at line 246, and it doesn't look wrong at all. Uh oh, where's the bug?

- Static typing is rigorous as you will have to potentially make more variables, but the programmer can rest easy knowing that variables can only take the data types they specifically declare. This makes for an easier debugging experience.

With the previous situation in mind: the program will crash on line 81, telling you that the a variable is being fed the wrong data type. You immediately see this, and rectify the problem, probably by making a new variable and potentially having to scroll through the entire program replacing some variables with the new one.

Comment: "Static typing means that YOU as the programmer declare the data type of the variable you're going to type out" Not if the language has type inference.

Comment: @sepp2k Type inference only happens once on compilation. The type still locks in after compiling. Dynamic on the other hand remains freeform post compilation. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598761/inferred-type-and-dynamic-typing

Comment: Yes, it happens at compile time, but it's not done by "YOU as the programmer" is my point. The way that this answer is phrased could give the impression that if you see a piece of code where variables are defined without a declared type, the language must be dynamically typed.

Comment: @sepp2k I see. Edited.